# Python astype() not working. How can I change object data types?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I've parsed the data from an XML file and created a Dataframe.

Below is an extract from the data, there are more columns on the actual one.

```
#Data parsed into the lists

dataDict = {}
dataDict['Id'] = []
dataDict['Title'] = []
dataDict['Location'] = []

for elem in tree.iter(tag = 'Id'):
    dataDict['Id'].append(elem.text)
for elem in tree.iter(tag = 'Title'):
    dataDict['Title'].append(elem.text)
for elem in tree.iter(tag = 'Location'):
    dataDict['Location'].append(elem.text)
```

```
#Dataframe is made

df = pd.DataFrame(dataDict, dataDict['Id'])
df.index.name = 'Id'
df.drop('Id', 1, inplace = True)

df
```

When I examine the current data frame types they are all objects

```
df.dtypes
```

```
#output

Title           object
Location        object
Company         object
dtype: object
```

I've tried to change the 'Title' column to string, however, it remains as an object.

```
df = df.astype({"Title": str})
```

```
#output

Title           object
Location        object
Company         object
dtype: object
```

I'm not sure what to do from here.
astype() seems to be the most suggested option but doesn't work.

Do I need to first save the data and read it in again before utilising pandas to change things?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/basics.html#dtypes):

> pandas has two ways to store strings.
>
> 1. `object` dtype, which can hold any Python object, including strings.
> 2. `StringDtype`, which is dedicated to strings.

Example

```
>>> df
    id
0  abc
1  def
2  ghi

>>> df.dtypes
id    object
dtype: object

>>> df.astype({'id': str}).dtypes  # first way to store string
id    object
dtype: object

>>> df.astype({'id': 'string'}).dtypes  # second way to store string
id    string
dtype: object
```